Why must I load jquery twice before it works
I have a strange problem. I have to load jquery twice and then it only works.
In the head of my html I load jquery:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

At the end of the html file I put the document ready function:
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    Code...
  });
</script>     

In the console of my browser I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function. So jquery is not correct loaded.
When I load jquery twice everything works fine:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here. Is this because jquery has not yet loaded before we get to the document ready function? Perhaps a delay needs to be built in?
Update
I think I found it. I load another jquery file:
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery-mobilemenu.min.js"></script>

In this code I see:
jQuery.noConflict()(function ($) {

When is disable the loading of this file, everything works fine. But I don't know why this is the problem...

I certainly cannot duplicate this.

Look at your script tag in the chrome inspector elements section. Does it have other attributes on it, like “async”?

I don't know exactly what you mean Andy, but I think there are no other attributes

Have you verified the error is coming from the line of code you posted in the question?

The error $ is not a function comes from $(document).ready(function(){

Place all <script> at the bottom right before the </body> end tag.

Done zer00ne, same result...

I think I found the problem, see update


But I don't know why this is the problem...

When jQuery.noConflict() executes, it restores the value of $ to whatever it was before jQuery loaded. As the jQuery documentation on noConflict says:

Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them.

Here is what happens when you load jQuery once and after that execute jQuery.noConflict():
Initially, $ is undefined. jQuery loads and saves that value of $ (undefined) and assigns jQuery to it. Then jQuery.noConflict() sets $ back to its previous value, which is undefined. That means your script will not work correctly, and $(document) will throw an error.
Here is what happens when you load jQuery twice and after that execute jQuery.noConflict():
Initially, $ is undefined. jQuery loads the first time and saves that value of $ (undefined) and assigns jQuery to it. Then jQuery is loaded a second time, and it also saves the value of $, but which is now jQuery (because of the first load of the jQuery library).
jQuery.noConflict() then executes and sets $ back to its previous value, but its previous value is now ... jQuery! That means your script will still work correctly.
To make it work with loading the jQuery library only once, you can do several things:

Don't let jQuery.noConflict() be executed, or

Replace in your own code every occurrence of $ with jQuery, or

Use the parameter of the callback you have, and name it $:
  $(document).ready(function($){
  //                        ^^^
    Code... using $
  });

or in the recommended syntax:
  $(function($) {
  //        ^^^
    Code... using $
  });

All code that uses $ for the jQuery object should have that parameter variable in its scope (or have it passed on).
See ready:

When $.noConflict() is used to avoid namespace conflicts, the $ shortcut is no longer available. However, the .ready() handler is passed a reference to the jQuery object that called the method. This allows the handler to use a jQuery object, for example as $, without knowing its aliased name.



